# Can we automate website testing on a mobile device?

Tags: android, ios, selenium, automated-tests

I am doing UI testing for a web application which needs to be tested on mobile devices as well. I have been using selenium for desktop testing, but I can't find any information on a mobile equivalent. I am learning swift and I'm experienced with java so if it's possible to do this,any pointers in the right direction would be of great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selenium for the same using appium as a bridge.

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/mobile-web/#android-mobile-web-automation 
should provide you more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Appium tool for testing. Download and Install the Android SDk,Appium server, node.js, microsoft .Net framework, Appium Jar file.
Yu can follow the link for Installation and Writing/running the Script using Java As language

https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html

http://www.seleniumeasy.com/appium-tutorials/install-appium-on-windows-step-by-step